# Computer tends to freeze and shutdown

Tags: windows-10, freeze, crash, shutdown, thinkcentre

I have a Lenovo ThinkCentre computer, Lenovo M92p with Intel Core i7 3770, 2 x 8GB Ram and a built in Intel HD 4000 Graphics, running Windows 10 Home.

The computer always runs quiet, and almost never heats up (at least not on the outside).

But still, the compute tends to freeze and shutdown sometimes.
I tried everything, formating, reinstalling windows and even replacing an hard drive, but nothing helps.
Sometimes the computer just freezes, I can't move the mouse or press anything, and after about a minute, it shuts down.

I have been having this problem for a while now so I noticed some patterns but still can't figure out how to connect the pieces...

The freezes can happen several times a day or even once a week, but on average they occur once a day.
I have noticed that if I don't use the computer for couple of days, after I start using it again it will work fine for a long time before starting to freeze again.

Recently after reading about similar problems online, I read about the windows event viewer, I searched for all events containing an unexpected shutdown or restart and I found the source of those events is Kernel-Power, their description says:

> The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This
>   error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or
>   lost power unexpectedly.

and, those events always (as far as I read in the event viewer) come after a FilterManager event saying this:

> File System Filter 'npsvctrig' (10.0,
>   ‎2015‎-‎07‎-‎10T06:14:31.000000000Z) has successfully loaded and
>   registered with Filter Manager.

Anyway, I am out of ideas, it is just frustrating to think that you can work on something important and suddenly your computer would just shutdown.

I could buy a new computer but I think it would be a waste, maybe the problem is just in a single component and I need to replace it.

### Notes:

- I didn't buy the computer on my own so I don't have a warranty.
- I have the computer for about two years, and the problem began about a year ago.
- The computer came with windows 7 and I moved to windows 10 about a month ago (fresh install).
- I dual boot windows 10 with Ubuntu 14.04, and the problem occurs in Ubuntu as well.

Comment: +1 For a well written question and enough back ground research. Did your PC come with Windows 10 pre-installed or you installed (or upgraded to Windows 10)? How about going back for warranty. Would that help. If they manufacturer cannot figure out what the problem could be - you might get a replacement.

Comment: @Prasanna thanks for answering, i updated the post to clarify some things i might have missed.

Comment: Probably you need to reseat the RAM, and maybe the CPU.

Comment: [Stress test the memory using memtest](http://www.memtest.org/), let it run for several hours or more to see if it triggers the shutdown, if it does, then it is a bad memory module.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I did not see you mention was running any kind of hardware diagnostics. I think you have ruled out software since it happens on two different operating systems. Most Lenovo systems have on-board diagnostics. Try hitting <kbd>F10</kbd> during the boot sequence; this should kick off the diagnostics for you.

It also sounds like you have a bad RAM stick or a bad RAM slot, assuming that the freezing is not necessarily occurring during a specific task but more randomly.